# Best way to store string array in local storage, Windows 8?

Tags: c#, windows-8

I have a question regarding Local Storage on Windows 8.

I want to store a string array of stock symbols. What is the best way to do something like this on Windows 8?

Browsing around, some have suggested store each string in the array into a new line in a text file, saved and retrieved from local storage.

If so, how would I achieve this? Are there better alternatives? Should I go down the path of sqlite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a sample demonstrates how to save a collection to local storage, please check it: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/CSWinStoreAppSaveCollection-bed5d6e6

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using the Isolated storage to store application values, possibly as serialised JSON, an object, etc. Here is a code example:

-- Set data

```
var localStorage = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
localStorage.Values[key] = value;
```

-- Get data

```
var localStorage = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
if(localStorage.Values.ContainsKey(key)
 return (T)localStorage.Values[key];
```

Although it's usually more practical to wrap the above in a helper class.

Other options would be writing a file to disk such as SQLite or an XML/JSON file but the above should work just fine for a small amount of data.

Comment: Thankyou for the answer! This works for me as well! (For anyone that reads this) If I could select two perfect answers, I would :)

Answer (score 0):

To save an array into local storage, you need to convert it to a string.

```
var localSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.current.localSettings;
var someSetting= new Array();

//Add values you want to store
someSetting.push("someValue");

//Change to string and save to local Storage
//toString will convert the array to a string with values separated by a comma
localSettings.values["someSettingInStorage"] = someSetting.toString();

//To retrieve the stored string value as a usable array
if (localSettings.values["someSetting"] != null)
    someSetting = (localSettings.values["someSetting"]).split(",");
```