# localStorage vs localSettings

Tags: javascript, windows, windows-10, win-universal-app

I'm trying to save settings in a Javascript Based Universal App in Windows 10.

I'm currently using localStorage and it seems to be working fine. But I've seen other posts that indicate I should use:
Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.current.localSettings

(see: [Best way to store string array in local storage, Windows 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14597478/best-way-to-store-string-array-in-local-storage-windows-8))

And this works as well.

But I'm wondering what is the recommended way? localStorage seems to be persistent even when I quit and reload the app. But will it always be persistent? And will it work on mobile? or is localSettings generally the way to go, what's the difference here guys?

Answer (score 1):

`ApplicationData.current.localSettings` is backed up in the cloud, which means that if the user buys a new phone (or resets their existing phone) and asks to restore settings from a backup of their old phone, the settings in `ApplicationData.current.localSettings` will be restored to the new phone. [This article](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2014/06/06/back-up-and-restore-your-app-on-windows-phone-8-1-part-2-app-data/) discusses app data backup in more detail.

Comment: I think you have mistaken *LocalSettings* with *RoamingSettings*.

Comment: @Romasz LocalSettings are backed up to the cloud but are not downloaded automatically by other devices. They are downloaded only during a "restore from backup" operation. RoamingSettings are backed up *and* are auto-downloaded on other devices.

Comment: I'm still not sure about this: [The lifetime of the app data is tied to the lifetime of the app. If the app is removed, all of the app data will be lost as a consequence...](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/xaml/mt299098.aspx). Do you have tried this or have any reference?

Comment: @Romasz - Raymond's [link](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2014/06/06/back-up-and-restore-your-app-on-windows-phone-8-1-part-2-app-data/) has this under **What You Need To Do**: "Local. This is the default storage location. It also supports storage of both unstructured data (files) and structured data (settings)... All data in Local is backed up to the cloud."

Comment: @chuex I've read it and that's why I'm confused - MSDN says that data is gone. As I've tried, the data should be gone, but maybe something has changed.

Comment: @Raymond  The quote from my comment above about local storage seems to indicate that both local files and settings are pushed to the cloud. Your answer implies (to me anyway) that only the settings are pushed. Can you clarify?

Comment: @chuex Do you know how to get back the backed up local data after for example app reinstallation?

Comment: I don't know whether files are backed up too. The only way I know of to recover backed up local data is to get a brand new phone (or reset your existing one) and then say you want to restore from a backup. There may be other ways but I don't know about them. I was just noting the difference between localStorage and localSettings: localSettings is backed up. (As for the "all of the app data will be lost" remark, it obviously includes the qualified 'that isn't backed up somewhere', in the same way that deleting a file causes the data to be lost, unless you backed it up somewhere.)

Comment: I guess [this may be a small explanation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn715805.aspx). Though it still doesn't say what happens to LocalFolder files, and seems that it's only backed up for purpose of upgrade/reset.

Comment: @Romasz No idea, I did not even know it was possible until now.

Comment: Local Storage is backed up for the device recovery. I have some home brew apps whose local folder moved from device to device with me.

Comment: @KaiBrummund Do you know if there are any limits for local folder? From what I've seen there is limited space on the cloud which you can see in phone settings, but it doesn't inform if there is limit per app. Also seems that this is only for phone recovery - once you reinstall the app, the data is removed.

Comment: True, only for the backup. The backup is removed, when the App is uninstalled. Haven't tried out the limits... Don't have a secondary phone to try out right now, but more than 100mb (that's what my example app here has on storage currently).